# Parsing the file divided with commas and equals signs

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a file that looks like as follows

```
name=helium,sign=he,number=2  
name=lithium,sign=li
name=gold,sign=au,number=79
```

Name, sign and number are keys in a map. If some key isn't listed it should become value "unidentified". Now I want to parse this comma/equal sign-divided file, but I'm not becoming the result I need and can't find and improve the mistake.

Here's what I have so far:

```
static Map<Table, String> periodicTable = new LinkedHashMap<Table, String>();
String[] list = fileToString(args[0]); // fileToString is to become the file content as a String array, where in the first field of the array is saved the first line of the file, in the second field - the second line and so on.
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    String[] element = list[i].split(",");

    for (int j = 0; j < element.length; j++) {
        String[] feature = element[j].split("=");
        if (feature[0].equals("name") 
             || feature[0].equals("sign") || feature[0].equals("number")) {
            feature[1] = periodicTable.get(feature[0]);
        } else {
            feature[1] = "unspecified";
        }
    }
}


public class Table {
private String name;
private String number;
private String sign;

public Table(String name, String number, String sign) {
    this.name = name;
    if (Integer.parseInt(number) >= 1 && Integer.parseInt(number) <= 118) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    this.sign = sign;
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me with this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you expect `periodicTable.get(feature[0]);` to do? (especially since `feature[0]` is one of `name`, `sign`, `number`?)

Comment: your curly brace is super confusing. please fix that first.

Comment: `feature[0]` is a `String`, how come you try to `get` from a `Map<Table, String>`?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a few comments to your code:

1. Your code for parsing file is out of main method, I assume that you missed it somewhere
2. Use StringTokenizer instead of split:

   StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
   while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
         String element = tokenizer.nextToken();
   }
3. Use foreach style instead of indexed for:

   for (String line : list) {
        // foo on line
   }
4. Try to use "equals" method of constant string instead of variables:

   if ("name".equals(feature[0])){
   }

   Because variable can be null, which can break your code.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively standard way to make your approach neater is to encapsulate the element attributes in an `enum`. That way you can expand the attributes you are storing very easily. It also avoids your ugly `if` statements. I've changed `Table` to `Element` here as it seems more natural to me that `Table` would be a list of `Element`.

```
public class Element {
    enum Attribute {
        NAME ("name", Element::setName),
        ATOMIC_NUMBER("number", Element::setNumber),
        SIGN("sign", Element::setSign);

        private final String attributeName;
        private final ValueSetter valueSetter;

        Attribute(String elementName, Element.ValueSetter valueSetter) {
            this.elementName = elementName;
            this.valueSetter = valueSetter;
        }

        public static void setElementValue(Element element, String attributeValue) {
            String[] attributeValuePair = attributeValue.split("=");
            String attributeName = attributeValuePair[0];
            String value = attributeValuePair[1];
            values().stream().filter(attributeName::equals)
                .forEach(attr -> attr.valueSetter.setValue(element, value));
        }
    }

    interface ValueSetter {
        void setValue(Element element, String value);
    }

    private Element() {
        // set default vaues
    }

    private static setName(Element element, String name) {
        element.name = name;
    }

    private static setSign(Element element, String sign) {
        element.sign = sign;
    }

    private static setNumber(Element element, String number) {
        element.number = Integer.parseInt(number);
    }

    public static Element readFromLine(String line) {
        Element element = new Element();
        line.split(",").stream()
            .forEach(attrVal -> Attribute.setElementValue(element, attrVal));
    }

    // same for setNumber, setSign
}
```

Then your code for reading lines can be quite a bit neater:

```
List<Element> table = lines.stream()
    .map(Element::readFromLine)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I've skipped lots of error checking here but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way to solve this problem with some of the classes of java api? Map, EnumMap or something else that doesn't come to my mind?